# how to add bookmarklet in IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, bookmarklet

I can't figure out the way to manually add a bookmarklet, there is no edit option for url.

I can save javascript bookmarklet embedded in webpages though.

Anyone know is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yea I think the only way is to put your bookmarklet into a webpage and save from there. It's not possible to do it in IE.